# Replacing element text with value from child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to replace my `<td>` elements contents with the value from a child input, but I'm having issues getting the values out.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS so far:**

```
$('input').closest('td').text($(this).val());
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to resolve this?

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because $(input).closest('td') returns an array of elements so you will have to loop through them first before you can get the value of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nenad Vracar's answer is very close but it doesn't replace the contents of the `<td>` like you need.

Instead, try this answer:

```js
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('td').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is with the instance of `this`. Once you traversed to the closest `<td>`, the value of `this` becomes the `<td>` and no longer the `<input>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `each` for each input, also if you use `text()` you will replace content of each `td` and remove inputs so instead you can use `append` or `prepend` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/632/)

```js
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('td').append($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text of the td elements and remove the inputs all in one go:

```
$('td').text(function() {
  return $(this).find('input').val()
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sp6521w2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will address your problem

```
//If you wantto change the conten on an event, say for example on textbox blur
$( "input[type='text']" ).blur(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var td = $(this).closest('td');
  td.empty()
  td.text( val )
});
```

// If all together you want to replace the content with value

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      var td = $(this).closest('td');
      td.empty()
      td.text( val )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('input').each(function() {
  $('input').closest('td').text($(this).val());
})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="value to steal"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want somebody to explain... It' because you try to get val on an `unknown` element.

Actually, `this` refers to the `scope`d `this` reference inside the function running your code.

---

So, you should do...

```
// I first ensure there is a td parent
$('td input').closest('td').each((function()
{
    // jQuery ensure that this keyword refers to the current 'td' element
    $(this).text($(this).find('input').val());
}));
```